# Create a new DIV class for every stored object in a database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, ejs

So I'm working on a warning system for discord. I have a dashboard made in EJS. I want to have a div class for every warn in a guild. How would I clone the div class for every warn in the database? I'm using MongoDB. So if a server has 3 warned users I want it to create 3 div classes. (NodeJS backend)

Comment: Be specific, what are you trying to achieve. Speak in terms of db operation.

Comment: So I want it to create an object for every query. So if I have 10 querys it should create 10 div classes on the website. But if I have 3 it should only create 3. The database will have have the data (as a database has)

Comment: So every time this query runs basically you want to add data in an array and in one go based on number of entries you will show that on page.

Comment: no, every time a user request data for a server it should get the data, clone the div class for the amount of query's for that server.

Comment: isn't it simply about running a dynamic piece on the frontend post getting the data? Is that what your question is?

Comment: Yea it is, I'm not the best on frotend as I'm mostly a backend developer